# My question is about how to cover Approval of Knowledge Article in Test class

Tags: code-coverage, knowledge, articles

When we insert Knowledge Article in test class then the status is Null and when I checked by using SeeAllData=true then I am not able to get such Knowledge Articles where status is pending and Actor Id is of a group member who approves articles.

When we insert KA in org then it goes to Draft status and on clicking the standard button 'Submit For Approval' it goes for approval, it doesn't look achievable to cover in it's test class.

**Apex Class** Query which needs to be covered:

```
List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> WorkItems : [SELECT ActorId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE (ActorId = : (Group who should approve) AND ProcessInstance.Status = 'Pending'])
```

**Test Class** code:

```
KArticle = new list<Knowledge__kav>();
  for (Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Knowledge__kav KArt = new Knowledge__kav();
    KArt.Title = 'test'+i
    KArt.UrlName = 'test'+i;
    KArt.sc_Product__c=Product1.Id;
    KArticle.add(faqArticle);
  }

insert KArticle;

Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');

for (Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  req1.setObjectId(KArticle[i].Id);
  Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippet what is not working in test class.?

Comment: Done, please let me know if you are aware of this issue